# IIS6 javascript routing issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, routes

I currently have the following within my view

```
function loadData() {
     var url = "/Testx.mvc/GetData";
     var id = "111111";
     var format = "html";

     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: "POST",
         dataType: format,
         data: "id=" + id,
         success: populateResults
     });
 }

 function populateResults(result) {
     $('#results').html(result);
 }
```

I also have a controller called TestxController with an action method called GetData(int? id).
Now the ajax call above works on Visual Studios 2008's built-in development server, but when i switch it to use IIS webserver it doesn't. It seems like the route isn't being found because I tried putting a break point on GetData but it doesn't even reach there. 
Does anyone know what i would need to do to fix this?

Edit: I've also tried the wildcard mapping method discussed at http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx and it worked perfectly. (Of course I had to remov the .mvc from the url)
Is there any way to get this to work with the .mvc extension?

Thanks

Comment: nevermind me. feeling dizzy. answer was completely lame. ^^

Comment: Some tips=>use $.get, use JSON to pass data (data: {id:id}), use <a href="http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx" title="route debugger">route debugger</a>. Might be useful.

Comment: Screw it. I don't understand how to format hyper-link nicely in comments.

Comment: You could use FireBug's console to see the ajax request being made, then check what the response from the server was. My guess is it's most likely a problem with the ISAPI rule for the .mvc extension in IIS.

Comment: Yeah. I second to Rudism. This sounds like a real answer. Here's a link with how-to: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Firebug doesn't show any request being made.

Comment: And zero javascript errors? :/

Comment: Yeah no js errors are being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Testx.mvc` at the root of your webserver? If your application is running in a virtual directory on IIS then the correct path would be something like `/YourApp/Testx.mvc/GetData`.

The Visual Studio built-in webserver might be placing `Testx.mvc` at root, which is why it works within VS.

If that is the case, then try using the relative path `Testx.mvc/GetData` rather than `/Testx.mvc/GetData`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an actual function called 'callback'? Just asking because it seems like you might mean to be calling 'populateResults' with a successful response.

Try this perhaps:

```
$.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     dataType: format,
     data: "id=" + id,
     success: function(results){$('#results').html(result)}
 });
```

Did you check your ISS setup to see if it supports the POST action? It might only be specifying the GET action... see http://haacked.com/images/haacked_com/WindowsLiveWriter/07de283cb368_B754/application-mappings_3.png

Comment: Yeah that didn't change anything. Thanks though